# Can anyone suggest an intervalometer for the Nikon D90?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon-d90, timelapse, intervalometer

I was wondering if anyone had suggestions for intervalometers for a Nikon D90.  The D90 lacks a remote port, so it has to be triggered either by USB or IR, which limits the 3rd party remotes it is compatible with quite a bit.

Comment: Ended up making my own.  A fully functional one can be put together for about $10 with a little bit of electronics knowledge.  Everything else available seemed way overpriced for what they did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Nikon D90 can in fact accept a wired remote.  It plugs into the GPS port which is the second rubber-covered area on the side of the D90.  While some cameras have separate ports, the D90 uses this single port for both purposes.

Here are a couple options from Amazon:

- [Satechi TR-M Timer Remote Control for Nikon D90](http://amzn.to/gwPy3g)
- [GSI Super Quality Multi-Function Timer Remote Control Shutter for Nikon](http://amzn.to/f6Tzv5)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making my own using some slapped together electronics.  Personally I think this is the best option considering how overpriced everything else is.

The setup is very simple.  I use a TI Launchpad with an MSP430G2231 to generate the IR signal. It's a $5 solution that is very flexible and I can set it up to do just about anything I need.

Here is a link to the schematic: Link to schematic :) (link broken)

Comment: Can you write up somewhere what you did?

Comment: Right here in the answer would be a nice "somewhere".

Comment: +1 for @Evan as I too would like the schematic and overview to build my own

Comment: Looking forward to the writeup.

Comment: I too built my own using the Arduino platform but it cannot go beyond 1/3 shutter speeds in bulb mode. So IR and CableTrigger only good for timelapse style photography (which is where the intervalometer shines!)

Comment: James, seeing your schematic (very nice work) and an image of the commercial thing (esp. its connector), I wonder how did you arrange a connector for your self-made intervalometer?

Comment: The device communicates with the camera by emulating an IR remote.